# 'function' object has no attribute 'getlist'

Tags: python, django, post, request

I have an error in my Django project
my project cannot understand the `getlist` function what is the problem and what can I do?

my code is this:

```
req = request.post.getlist('name1[]')
```

and the error is this:

```
AttributeError at /
'function' object has no attribute 'getlist'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try , `req = request.POST.getlist('name1[]')`

the usage is described in [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST).

In an HttpRequest object, the GET and POST attributes are instances of django.http.QueryDict. getlist is method of QueryDict and not HttpRequest.

Comment: Same error as above?

Comment: so how can I create a list of my requests?

Comment: Assuming that you have multiple form inputs with the name attribute set to "name1[]" and you want to retrieve all their values in a list, then the getlist() function should return the list only. Or if you are asking something else which I have missed out, please correct me